# How can I convert a string such as 5.7303333333e+02 to decimal in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, decimal, data-conversion

I'm trying to convert strings such as `5.7303333333e+02` to the `decimal` type. I've tried using `[decimal]::TryParse` but the return value is false.

Is there a method similar to `[datetime]::parseexact`, or any clean way to convert these strings? Or am I going to have to parse out the `e+02` and do that math separately?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about :

```
[int]"5.7303333333e+02"
[decimal]"5.7303333333e+02"
```

Comment: +1 it works. But I wonder what casting mechanism is used in the background, if it is not `[decimal]::TryParse("5,7303333333e+02", [ref] $dec)`. The problem is the unsupported scientific notation because `[decimal]::TryParse("5,7303333333", [ref] $dec)` does work... See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557.aspx

Comment: I'm surprised that worked but `[decimal]::TryParse` doesn't. Much cleaner looking than using TryParse anyway.

Comment: @davor: Using `Trace-Command TypeConversion { [decimal]'5.7303333333e+02' } -PSHost `, you can see that PowerShell catches the format exception and re-tries the conversion by parsing with `[double]` and then converting to `[decimal]`.

Comment: this doesn't work. `[decimal]'5.730333333333333333333333333e+02'` will return an incorrect value

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR:

You need to specify [`NumberStyles.Float`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=net-7.0) when using `Parse` or `TryParse`

```
PS C:\> $s = '5.7303333333333333333333333e+02'
PS C:\> $style = [Globalization.NumberStyles]::Float
PS C:\> $culture = [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('en-US')
PS C:\> [decimal]::Parse($s, $style)
573.03333333333333333333333
PS C:\> [decimal]$dec = 0
PS C:\> [decimal]::TryParse($s, $style, $culture, [ref] $dec)
True
PS C:\> $dec
573.03333333333333333333333
```

or append the [`d` suffix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24474017/995714) directly

```
PS C:\> Invoke-Expression ($s + 'd')
573.0333333333333333333333333
```

---

As [Emperor XLII commented above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16966978/995714#comment24956625_16966978), **`[decimal]"5.7303333333e+02"` does not actually work** because it'll ***convert to decimal through double***. Try adding more digits and you'll immediately realized that the output isn't correct anymore:

```
PS C:\> Trace-Command TypeConversion { [decimal]'5.7303333333e+02' } -PSHost
DEBUG: TypeConversion Information: 0 : Converting to decimal.
DEBUG: TypeConversion Information: 0 : Exception converting to decimal: "Input string was not in a correct format.". Converting to decimal passing through double.
DEBUG: TypeConversion Information: 0 : Numeric Conversion through System.Double.
573.03333333
PS C:\> [decimal]'5.7303333333e+02'
573.03333333
PS C:\> [decimal]'5.730333333333333333333333333e+02' # doesn't work
573.033333333333
PS C:\> 5.730333333333333333333333333e+02d           # correct value
573.0333333333333333333333333
```

As you can see if we use the [`d` suffix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7) for decimal we'll get the correct high-precision value, so one simple trick is just spawning a new shell to normalize the value although that'll be obviously slow, or use [Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.1)

```
PS C:\> $d = '5.730333333333333333333333333e+02'
PS C:\> [decimal]$(powershell -com ($d + 'd'))
573.0333333333333333333333333
PS C:\> Invoke-Expression ($d + 'd'))
573.0333333333333333333333333
```

But why doesn't `TryParse` work? The reason is because the default style used by [Decimal.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.parse?view=netcore-3.1#System_Decimal_Parse_System_String_) and [Decimal.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1#System_Decimal_TryParse_System_String_System_Decimal__) is like this

```
[ws][sign][digits,]digits[.fractional-digits][ws]
```

which **doesn't allow the exponent**. If you read [Parse's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.parse?view=netcore-3.1#System_Decimal_Parse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_) you'll see that the full number format is

```
[ws][$][sign][digits,]digits[.fractional-digits][e[sign]digits][ws]
```

Where `[e]` is

> - The 'e' or 'E' character, which indicates that the value is represented in exponential notation. The s parameter can represent a number in exponential notation if style includes the [`NumberStyles.AllowExponent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=netcore-3.1#System_Globalization_NumberStyles_AllowExponent) flag.

That means you need to use `NumberStyles.Float` (which includes `NumberStyles.AllowExponent`) as above to make it work

Comment: In the first piece of code I'm getting an error `[ref] cannot be applied to a variable that does not exist`. `$dec = [decimal]::Parse($s, $style)` is the fix.

Comment: @Ste no, `Parse` and `TryParse` are different things. The correct fix is to declare the variable before using: `[decimal]$dec = 0`