# What's the proper way to initialize an unsigned integer to 0xFFFFFFFF in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

My CRC calculation algorithm requires that I initialize a 32-bit unsigned integer variable to 0xFFFFFFFF (all 1's in binary so that I can use the variable as a bitmask).  If I just write `[uint32]$r=0xFFFFFFFF`, I get the following error message:

> Cannot convert value "-1" to type "System.UInt32". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for a UInt32."

The syntax I'm currently using is `[uint32]$r="0xFFFFFFFF"`, but it seems a bit over the top with the string to integer conversion (I'm coming from the C/C++ programming world).  I'm pretty new to Powershell, so I was wondering if Powershell has a more efficient/straightforward way of initializing a variable like this.

Comment: You can use `[UInt32] "0xFFFFFFFF"` - why is that "over the top"?

Comment: You don't need the string.  PowerShell interprets `0xFFFFFFFF` as a hex value.

Comment: Yes, but you can't cast directly as `UInt32` without the quotes--because `0xFFFFFFFF` casts to `Int` value `-1` on right-hand side first. The quotes avoid the right-hand cast and allows left-hand cast to work.

Answer (score 6):

How about `[UInt32]::MaxValue`.

The value of this constant is 4,294,967,295; that is, hexadecimal 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: This can be validated with the following snippet: `'{0:x}' -f [UInt32]::MaxValue`

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell doesn't have any syntax for `UInt32` literals, but you could cast an `Int64` literal to `[uint32]` with [the `l` type postfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474017/what-is-the-full-list-of-number-suffixes-in-powershell):

```
[uint32]0xFFFFFFFFl
```