# How to convert string to decimal in powershell?

Tags: powershell, decimal, data-conversion

I have a string,

```
$string = "2,55"
```

How to convert this string to decimal?

Comment: Please refere [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)..Have you tried any code or do you have any research content to show for this issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a string such as 5.7303333333e+02 to a decimal type in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966938/how-can-i-convert-a-string-such-as-5-7303333333e02-to-a-decimal-type-in-powersh)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short -

```
[decimal]$string.Replace(",", ".")
```

Comment: love the conciseness !

Comment: @jyao **consise != correct**. Try running that on .NET Core on a comma locale and it'll fail immediately

Answer (score 6):

Another way of converting this (not necessarily better) is using the `ToDecimal` method with a specific culture. Here I'm using the standard french culture.

```
 [System.Convert]::ToDecimal("2,55",[cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('fr-FR'))
 2.55
```

Answer (score 5):

You should **convert using the current locale**. Replacing `,` with `.` **isn't reliable and is slightly slower** (because another string must be created). Both [Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.parse?view=netcore-3.1#System_Decimal_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) and [TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1#System_Decimal_TryParse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_System_Decimal__) have a culture parameter that you can use

```
PS D:\> $string = "2,55"
PS D:\> $culture = Get-Culture
PS D:\> [decimal]::Parse($string, $culture)
2.55
PS D:\> [decimal]$dec = 0
PS D:\> [decimal]::TryParse($string, [Globalization.NumberStyles]::Float, $culture, [ref]$dec)
True
PS D:\> $dec
2.55
```

If you know the locale of the input then **parse directly in that locale** by using [`GetCultureInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.getcultureinfo?view=netcore-3.1)

```
$culture = [cultureinfo]::GetCultureInfo('fr-FR')
```

Note that if the string contains the exponent like "2,55e2" then **none of the current other answers** actually work (although it may *appear* to work). For more details read [How can I convert a string such as 5.7303333333e+02 to decimal in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63516060/995714)

Answer (score -1):

To force a conversion to a specific datatype, prefix the value or variable with the type in square brackets, this is known as a Cast Operator and forces the chosen datatype:

```
$string = "100.5"
$decimal = [decimal]$string

$string + 0.5
# Outputs 100.10.5

$decimal + 0.5
# Outputs 101,0
```

More information can be found [here](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-datatypes.html)

Comment: That's helpful in general, but note that PowerShell's casts always apply the _invariant_ culture, where the decimal mark is `.`. Therefore,  the OP's input string wouldn't yield the desired result: `[decimal] "2,55"` -> `255`; that is, the `,` was interpreted as a thousands-grouping symbol and effectively ignored.

Comment: @mklement0, thanks for the feedback. I missed this detail.